# function not detecting variable

Tags: php

I currently have an index.php file and on the top i have

```
$pagetitle == "home";

function isThisHome(){
    if($pagetitle == "home"){
        $output = $output . 'this is home!';
    }else{
        $output = $output . 'this is not home!';
    }
    return $output;
}
echo isThisHome();
```

I'd expect that it would echo "this is home!" but instead it's echoing "this is not home!". Can someone help correct me to make it say "this is home"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access variables outside the scope of a function, you need to qualify the global variable with [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) qualifier inside the function.

Also the assignment operator is [`ASSIGN`](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.assign.php) (`=`), so [`IS_EQUAL`](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.is-equal.php) (`==`) is not the same.

```
$pagetitle = "home";

function isThisHome(){
    global $pagetitle; 
    if($pagetitle == "home"){
        $output = $output . 'this is home!';
    } else{
        $output = $output . 'this is not home!';
    }
    return $output;
}
echo isThisHome();
```

Comment: It is not about the variable scope. Please look at the question and code again. He used two `==` instead of 1

Comment: Yes, but he still has 2 problems. He's probably not seeing warnings because his `php.ini` file.

Comment: @Dacaspex - It's about both

Comment: oops sorry $pagetitle = "home"; i accidentally put two in there that was my fault. but still showing "this is not my home"

Comment: Whoa thank you! this one worked! I'm super excited thanks again this was extremely fast.

Comment: be sure to accept the answer that worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$pagetitle == "home";
```

Should be

```
$pagetitle = "home";
```

Comment: oops sorry $pagetitle = "home"; i accidentally put two in there that was my fault. but still showing "this is not my home"